# GroupBox internal margins

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I set margins of `label` and `label2` to zero relatively to internal `groupBox2`. As can be seen from the picture, `label` is along the border of `groupBox2` while `label2` has the additional margin.

What is the internal margin of `GroupBox`?

[image]

```
GroupBox {
    id: groupBox1
    x: 5
    y: 302
    width: 142
    height: 90
    checked: false
    flat: false
    title: qsTr("Group Box")

    Label {
        id: label
        text: qsTr("Label")
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 0
        anchors.left: groupBox2.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 0
    }

    GroupBox {
        id: groupBox2
        y: 16
        height: 45
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 0
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 0
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 0
        title: qsTr("Group Box2")

        Label {
            id: label2
            text: qsTr("Label2")
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GroupBox` has style which defines internal margins and their size depends on the platform your program is running on.

Check out `GroupBox` style in your qt installation directory e.g. `/path_to_installation/Qt5.5.0/5.5/Src/qtquickcontrols/src/controls/Styles/Base/GroupBoxStyle.qml`, there are also custom styles in subdirectories for various platforms: `Desktop/GroupBoxStyle.qml`, `WinRT/PC/GroupBoxStyle.qml`, `iOS/GroupBoxStyle.qml`, etc.

Here's part from `Base/GroupBoxStyle.qml`:

```
/*! The margin from the content item to the groupbox. */
padding {
    top: (control.title.length > 0 || control.checkable ? TextSingleton.implicitHeight : 0) + 10
    left: 8
    right: 8
    bottom: 6
}
```

So left margin is probably set to `8` in your case.

`GroupBox` has undocumented property `style` which can be used to set custom style. `GroupBox.style` and `GroupBoxStyle.qml` are marked as internal so be careful when updating Qt, they can be changed in future Qt releases without warning and code using it could stop working.

So to set different margin size you could copy `GroupBoxStyle.qml` to your project and use it like this:

```
GroupBox {
    style: GroupBoxStyle {
        padding.left: 0 //your desired padding value
    }
}
```